# Cannot Start mySQL Daemon with Error "mysqld from pid file ... ended"

Tags: mysql, innodb, linux

I cannot get MySQL to run. It was working just fine hours ago, but upon starting, repeatedly ends without telling me very much. Here are my logs

```
[myusername@location ~/mysql]$ ./bin/mysqld_safe --log-error=my-errors &
[2] 14747
[1]    Done                          ./bin/mysqld_safe
[myusername@location ~/mysql]$ 150708 20:55:25 mysqld_safe Logging to '/rc00/d84/myusername/mysql/data/my-errors.err'.
150708 20:55:25 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /rc00/d84/myusername/mysql/data
150708 20:57:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /rc00/d84/myusername/mysql/data/ovid03.u.washington.edu.pid ended
```

Attempting to start the regular way leads to the following:

```
[myusername@location bin]$ mysqld
mysqld: Command not found.
[myusername@location bin]$ cd ..
[myusername@location mysqlver]$ ./bin/mysqld
150708 21:04:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150708 21:04:09 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150708 21:04:09 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150708 21:04:09 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150708 21:04:09 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150708 21:04:09 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
```

The last few lines repeat over and over again, as it tries to start.

I was reading around that there could be problems with ownership of files and folders, could this be it?

```
[myusername@location ~]$ ls -l mysql
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 12 Jul  1  2013 bin -> mysqlver/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 29 Jul  1  2013 data -> /rc00/d84/myusername/mysql-data
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 13 Jul  1  2013 docs -> mysqlver/docs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 16 Jul  1  2013 include -> mysqlver/include
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 12 Jul  1  2013 lib -> mysqlver/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 12 Jul  1  2013 man -> mysqlver/man
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername users   40 Jul  1  2013 mysqlver -> /usr/local/mysql-5.5.18-linux2.6-x86_64/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 16 Jul  1  2013 scripts -> mysqlver/scripts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 14 Jul  1  2013 share -> mysqlver/share
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 18 Jul  1  2013 sql-bench -> mysqlver/sql-bench
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 22 Jul  1  2013 support-files -> mysqlver/support-files
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 14 Jul  1  2013 tests -> mysqlver/tests
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername nousers 12 Jul  1  2013 usr -> mysqlver/usr
```

I feel really lost right now and thank you in advance for your help. I do have a backup of the sql folder from a week ago, but am not yet ready to try putting that on to the server just yet.

Comment: Why can't you just run MySQL as a service?

Comment: I don't think it's a permissions issue. Note that all the files are rwx to everybody. Don't run the process in the background and see does that give any more info on startup.

Comment: `$ ps auwwx | grep mysqld | grep -v grep` ... does that return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out the problem a long time ago but in the panic of fixing it, failed to update here. The problem turned out to be that the server had a fixed limit on the size of MySQL, imposed by admins higher up the food chain. The previous admin failed to let me know about it, and also failed to check the size of the database until we hit the wall. Once we opened up more space for the server, we were good to go

Answer (score 0):

```
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
```

Perhaps another copy of mysqld is still running?

Only run it as a service.